# What is this functionality, and how can it be achieved?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sms

This functionality is triggered by an app called BankID used to verify my identity when logging in to my online bank here in Norway.

What kind of functionality is triggered? How is it triggered? Can I do it?

I suspect that this functionality is triggered by SMS, but I am not sure.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It can't send SMS on your behalf unless you see the composer UI. It probably simply connects to bank's web service. You could check what it does with Wireshark or some other network traffic  sniffing tool. This call is almost certainly made via SSL don't expect to see much that will make sense. You could do it if you get specifications (white papers) from the bank or reverse engineer the call & response (this might be against the law).

Comment: Hi rokjarc. As you can see on the screenshots, this app triggers functionality completely outside of a regular app sandbox. This is a whole other part of the OS... I am suspecting that the functionality is not directly connected to the app downloaded from the AppStore, but I am not sure...

Comment: Which app? What happens exactly? The screenshots show barely anything, and most people don't speak Norwegian.

Comment: Have a look at lxt's answer. It explains the nature of this "app" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, BankID is a collaboration between Norwegian banks and network operators. The latter is the important part - what you're seeing on device is a [SIM Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Application_Toolkit), part of the GSM standard that allows very simple applications to be stored and run directly from the SIM card.

It's triggered by sending remote GSM commands to your device, which then launch the application (so kind of like SMS, but at a lower level). What you're seeing is how iOS displays SIM applications. You can read the wikipedia link above to find out more about these applications and how they work.

This does mean that it's something you won't be able to use yourself - unless, of course, you're a network operator!